# Regular expression to allow user to enter only text, not alphanumeric

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I know it may be very easy for many of you but I am stuck with it. Its killing my time. As I researched on net, I got many regular expression to check for numbers, digit and alphanumeric but I am unable to change the code to meet my requirement. I want user to enter only text in the given textbox(as in real a person name does not contain any special characters or any digit). Spaces are allowed because user might want to enter first name and last name.

I am trying with following using Jquery validation

```
jQuery(function(){
            jQuery("#userName").validate({
                expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
                message: "Please enter the Required field(Only text is allowed)"
            });
            jQuery("#userName").validate({
                expression: "if (isNaN(VAL)) return true; else return false;",
                message: "Please enter Only text"
            });
            jQuery("#userName").validate({
                expression: "if (VAL.match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$/)) return **false**; else return **true**;",
                message: "Please do not enter alpha numeric values"
            });
```

1st 2 validations are working perfectly. Last one is related to my query. Please help me out. Many many thanks in advance. :)

Thanks everybody specially to npinti, below code is working now.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        reg = new RegExp('^[A-Za-z ]+$');
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        jQuery(function(){
            jQuery("#userName").validate({
                expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
                message: "Please enter the Required field(Only text is allowed)"
            });
            jQuery("#userName").validate({

                expression: "if(reg.test(VAL)) return true; else return false;",
                message: "Please enter only text"
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex should match what you need: `^[A-Za-z ]+$`. This will match any letter (lower and upper case, denoted by `A-Z` and `a-z`) and spaces. The `+` denotes that it will match one or more repetitions of, and the `^` and `$` anchors instruct the regex engine to match the entire string.

If you want a more robust regex, meaning one that will cater for non english letters, you could use something like so: `^[\p{L} ]+$`. This is the same as before, the only difference being that `\p{L}` caters for any letter (both upper and lower) in any language (taken from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html))

EDIT: As per @thg435 suggestion, `\p{L}` will not work since this is not supported by JavaScirpt.

Comment: Hi npinti... Thanks for the response. My simple doubt is when I enter name1 or 1name or name@ or @name, it should not be allowed to be entered. But he can insert string(Name). I tried with your regex. Its not working. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ShashiRoy: Can you please update your question to what have you tried and what failed?

Comment: Hi npinti... Sorry for the last post. Its working perfectly. There was an error from my side in applying your code in the script section. Code which is working now I've updated with my question above. Thanks a lot for saving my time :)

Comment: @ShashiRoy: No worries. Note however, that in your example, you left out the space.

Comment: I don't think Javascript supports `\p{L}`.

Comment: To add to thg435 has said, ECMA regex doesn't have good support to match Unicode text. The only thing supported is range in character class.

Comment: Hi npinti... You are awesome... I forgot to validate this regex against space... Had I tried it, I would really have got the error... Again thanks a lot for the perfect help... Thank you so much... :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should initiate regex object and not using VAL.match. Try this for third validation:

```
jQuery(function(){
   First initiate regex
    reg = /[a-zA-Z0-9_-]/ 
    //or 
    reg = new RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9_-]');

    jQuery("#userName").validate({
      expression: "if (reg.test(VAL)) return **false**; else return **true**;",
      message: "Please do not enter alpha numeric values"
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi... thanks for the response. Its working good for checking alphanumeric values but its not allowing to enter simple texts also.